# asp.net mvc Modifying CSS of specific items in view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view model that I am rendering with EditorFor(), and I would like to be able to set the css of specific elements in the model. So for instance:

```
public class BasicIdentification
{
    //Primitive Types
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public String FName { get; set; }

     [Display(Name = "Last  Name")]
    public String LName { get; set; }
```

}

If I wanted to set the CSS class for FName and LName, how would I do this? How do I "connect" the css to my model. I want to be able to use EditorFor() an dhave it render the way I want it to.

Comment: Your model shouldn't have any css attached to it. One of the major tenants of MVC is separating the model from its representation in the UI. What you want to do instead is make changes to the css in your view.

Comment: I wanted to be able to make FName in a left column and LName in a right column, while still only using EditorForModel() to render my entire model, as I have custom templates to render certain elements of my model.

Comment: @JohnEdwards What do you mean by put on the left? On the left of what? Left align, you mean?

Comment: Yes. If I wanted a 2 column format for my model, how would I do this while still only using EditorForModel()? Or is this even possible? Otherwise I would just have to call EditorFor() for every property in my model.

Comment: @JohnEdwards to be honest, I hardly use HtmlHelpers. I'm much more into building the HTML myself, to avoid things like this.

Comment: @JohnEdwards it appears you need a level of customization in your app for which EditorForModel cannot support. Either modify or build a new helper or write up the HTML manually. Sam offers an answer that still uses helpers but gives you more customization than what you're using now.

Answer (score 6):

In the View you would see something like this by default

```
<div class="display-label">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LName)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LName)
</div>
```

To add a CSS class or something you simply do this.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LName, new { @class="classname" })
```

class itself is a reserved word for .NET so the @class just means to use the HTML class attribute.

Comment: But what if I wanted to do something like put FName in a left column and LName in a right column? I don't see how I can set "divs" up to modify the positions of certain elements in my model .Thanks.

Comment: Sam, welcome to Stack Overflow and congrats for you first upvoted answer =)

Comment: John Edwards you would probably want to give your FName Div a class and your LName div a class to make the Div's themselves go left or right depending on where you want them.  Or you could remove the div's that are put there by the default template and the classes that you put on the textboxes will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to "set the CSS" per say, but I don't see a problem with including the state of in your view model which can then be translated into an HTML class which you can use to style it appropriately in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Create an EditorTemplate for your BasicIdentification class called BasicIdentification.cshtml.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FName)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FName)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LName)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LName)
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

Then whenever you do `@Html.EditorForModel()` and your model is your `BasicIdentification` class, then the above HTML will be generated.

**Edit:** Additional information about Editor Templates: http://dineshkumara.blogspot.ca/2011/06/mvc-3-razor-editor-template.html